# Tokeninput plugin:- Altering ajax request URL

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, jquery-tokeninput

I am retrieving data from a specific URL but in order to recieve the correct results I need to remove a paramater.

The URL currently being generated by token input is:-

http://developer.echonest.com/api/v4/artist/suggest?api_key=W8ZWNWH6N&name=radiohead&_=1320665341820

I need to remove the last part :-

&_=1320665341820

How can I achieve this so that token input just generates a URL with the following format:-

http://developer.echonest.com/api/v4/artist/suggest?api_key=W8ZWNWH6N&name=radiohead

My current initialization code for 'Token input' is:-

```
$("#similar_artists").tokenInput("http://developer.echonest.com/api/v4/artist/suggest?api_key=W8ZWEXAMPLEWH6N", {


hintText: "Please begin typing the name of a famous artist who has the kind of sound you are looking for. You may select as many as you wish.",
theme: "facebook",
onAdd: function (item) {

                filterDatatable();
                },
onDelete: function (item) {

                    filterDatatable();
                },

searchDelay: "0",
tokenDelimiter: ", ",
animateDropdown: true,
preventDuplicates: true,
deleteText: "",
tokenValue: "name",
crossDomain: false,
tokenLimit: "6",
queryParam: "name",
noResultsText: "There are no valid artists that match your request, please try again.",
onResult: function (data) {

                    return data['response']['artists'];
                }

});

});
```